# ListView.setSelection does not work

Tags: java, android, listview

I have one ListView with custom adapter.When I rotate screen it is always go to the first position. I've tried save last position and then with SetSelection set position in the right place,but no luck for now.

Piece of code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_words, container, false);
    lvIrregularVerbs = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        lastposition=savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
    }
    fulllist(lst);
    irregularVerbsAdapter = new IrrVerbsAdapter(getActivity(), lst, MainActivity.db);
    lvIrregularVerbs.setAdapter(irregularVerbsAdapter);
    lvIrregularVerbs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        //some stuff


        }
    });
    lvIrregularVerbs.setSelection(lastposition);
    return root;    
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position", lvIrregularVerbs.getLastVisiblePosition());
}
```

But if I set a constant in SetSelection it's all works fine. 
I've looked and tried everything,and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Are you sure that you are geetting that value correctly, could you please print it

Comment: Indeed. The code where `lastposition` is set is missing.

Comment: @greenapps well I've set **lastposition** right after **lvIrregularVerbs = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);**.If that what you mean.

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić When I debug it after fragment was destroyed I always see correct **lastposition** value.

Comment: Did you debug in onCreate or in onDestroyed

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić in onCreateView. **lastposition** always has right value but **lvIrregularVerbs.setSelection(lastposition);** does't affect anything.

Comment: is yourchoice mode single?

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić yes.

Comment: You do realize that the method you are using will set the item on the index to be on the  top of the screen not select it right?

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić yeah,but it always set first element on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post your selection code somewhere else - in onResume or try to call new Handler().post(new Runnable() { ..run(){list.setPosition(pos);}});

Comment: no resuluts,but I discover that **onCreateView** is called twice,and 'cause **lastposition=0** **SetSelection** does't work.Maybe it's *MainActivity.java* problem.

Comment: And how are you storing your last position? My approach that seems to be working fine is store it into arguments of fragment in onPause and restore it in onResume .. like getArguments().putInt(POS_KEY, mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());